# How to get the current class name at runtime?

Tags: c#, class, reflection, abstract

I'm trying to get a current class name into a string.

For example:

```
public class Marker : Mark
{
    string currentclass = ???;
}

public abstract class MiniMarker : Mark
{
}
```

I'd like to get the string from `Marker` class so I do not have to put it inside each abstract class I make from it.

I want the string to be `MiniMarker`, or what ever the abstract class is named.

I tried `MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().DeclaringType`, but it did not work.

Comment: Is your sample correct? How is Marker and MiniMarker related, Marker is based on Mark.

Comment: Your example and your reference to abstract classes makes no sense. Your code belongs in the abstract base class, `Mark`. The classes derived from it are concrete unless you have a multilevel hierarchy.

Answer (score 54):

```
   this.GetType().Name
```

should return a Class name

Comment: This is almost right, its returning "Base.Tools.MiniMarker" i need to have it only be "MiniMarker".

Comment: @Craig - It is a string. Just get anything right to the last `.`.

Comment: @Craig Really? I just tried this and I only got the class name. `FullName` features the namespace, as does `ToString()`.

Comment: Sorry i forgot to add .Name, this is working. Thank you.

Comment: Is there a way to make it work in a static method, without this keyword?

Comment: Yes, try this within your static method. To use MethodBase you need to using System.Reflection namespace.
MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().DeclaringType.Name

Comment: This should work also in static context:
 typeof(MyProgram).Name

Answer (score 6):

This should do:

```
this.GetType().ToString()
```

Comment: For static methods: `MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().DeclaringType.Name`