# Get current class at runtime in a static method?

Tags: c#, reflection, static, abstract

How can I get the type (not a name string, but a type itself) of the current class, in a static method of an abstract class?

```
using System.Reflection; // I'll need it, right?

public abstract class AbstractClass {

    private static void Method() {

        // I want to get CurrentClass type here

    }

}

public class CurrentClass : AbstractClass {

    public void DoStuff() {

        Method(); // Here I'm calling it

    }

}
```

This question is very similar to this one:

[How to get the current class name at runtime?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12035426/how-to-get-the-current-class-name-at-runtime)

However, I want to get this information from inside the static method.

Comment: Take a look at this: [GetType in static method](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7839691/gettype-in-static-method)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
public abstract class AbstractClass
{
    protected static void Method<T>() where T : AbstractClass
    {
        Type t = typeof (T);

    }
}

public class CurrentClass : AbstractClass
{

    public void DoStuff()
    {
        Method<CurrentClass>(); // Here I'm calling it
    }

}
```

You can gain access to the derived type from the static method simply by passing the type as a generic type argument to the base class.

Comment: Yeah, I've figured to use generics myself in the meantime.

Comment: If you use generics like that, consider what will happen if you've got `ExtendedClass : CurrentClass`: `Method` will get `CurrentClass`, not `ExtendedClass`.

Answer (score 1):

I think you will have to either pass it in like the other suggestion or create a stack frame, I believe if you put an entire stack trace together though it can be expensive.

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.stacktrace.aspx

Answer (score 1):

if you are calling this static method only from derived classes you can use 'System.Diagnostics.StackTrace' like

```
abstract class A
{
    public abstract string F();
    protected static string S()
    {
        var st = new StackTrace();
        // this is what you are asking for
        var callingType = st.GetFrame(1).GetMethod().DeclaringType;
        return callingType.Name;
    }
}

class B : A
{
    public override string F()
    {
        return S(); // returns "B"
    }
}

class C : A
{
    public override string F()
    {
        return S();  // returns "C"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The method can't be `static` if you're going to call it without passing in a type.  You can do this:

```
public abstract class AbstractClass {
    protected void Method() {
        var t = GetType(); // it's CurrentClass
    }
}
```

If you also need it to be accessible from a `static` context, you can add an overload, even a generic overload, e.g.:

```
public abstract class AbstractClass {
    protected static void Method<T>() {
        Method(typeof(T));
    }
    protected static void Method(Type t) {
        // put your logic here
    }
    protected void Method() {
        Method(GetType());
    }
}
```